# Swift convert javascript regualr expression into ios regular expression

Tags: ios, swift, regex

Regular expression in Javascript: `(^04[0-9]{8})|(^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$)`.

I am trying regular expression for Australian phone no validation. How do I convert this regular expression into iOS regular expression?

```
let Format = "^04[0-9]{8})|(^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$"
let Predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", Format)
return Predicate.evaluate(with: fieldText)
```

Comment: Update your question with your relevant Swift code showing your attempt. Clearly explain the issues you are having.

Comment: Your regem in Swift would be the same as in Java

Comment: i tried that code.it is not working

Comment: show your tried code

Comment: i added my code

Comment: Well, you are missing `(` in the beginning and `)` in the end. Otherwise there should be no difference.

Comment: in your regex, this [0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4} is equivalent to [0-9]{10} and 04[0-9]{8}|[0-9]{10} is further equivalent as [0-9]{10}. Also you haven't properly put $ (end of input) properly like you have put ^ beginning of input. You need proper parenthesis.

Comment: I would recommend to use https://github.com/marmelroy/PhoneNumberKit for any phone number validation or formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are missing only parentheses `(` and `)` in the beginning and in the end.

```
let fieldText = "0401234567"
let pattern = "(^04[0-9]{8})|(^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$)"
let matches = fieldText.range(of: pattern, options: .regularExpression) != nil
print(matches) // true
```

or, with `NSPredicate`:

```
let fieldText = "0401234567"
let pattern = "(^04[0-9]{8})|(^[0-9]{2}[0-9]{4}[0-9]{4}$)"
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "SELF MATCHES %@", pattern)
let matches = predicate.evaluate(with: fieldText)
print(matches) // true
```

The regular expression still looks pretty weird though.